# Device Orientation API returns different values for desktop browsers

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, firefox, device-orientation

Using the [Device Orientation API demo](http://www.audero.it/demo/device-orientation-api-demo.html) on desktop Firefox 44 and Chrome Version 47.0.2526.80 m return different results for the coordinates.

Firefox returns `null` and Chrome `0`. So far so good.

With this piece of code I am trying to check `deviceorientation` data.

So first I check if the Device Orientation event is supported and both Firefox and Chrome say it is with the first alert firing.

```
if(window.DeviceOrientationEvent) {
  alert("Device Orientation Event is supported.");

  window.addEventListener('deviceorientation', function(event) {
    var alpha = event.alpha;
    var beta = event.beta;
    var gamma = event.gamma;

    // https://stackoverflow.com/a/27550756
    if(alpha === null && typeof alpha === "object")
      alert(alpha);
  }, false);
}
```

However only Chrome correctly returns the second alert as `null` whereas Firefox does not trigger the alert at all. But it should do so looking at the data results from the Device Orientation API demo.

I have also made sure to specifically check for `null` and not `""`, `undefined`, `false`, `0`, or `NaN` as per [How do I check for null values in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27550756/1010918)?

So how do I get Firefox to actually fire the second alert with the data of the `deviceorientation` ?

Related questions:

[Device Orientation not working firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9898325/device-orientation-not-working-firefox)

['deviceorientation' in Firefox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22524954/deviceorientation-in-firefox)

[Different gyroscope values in chrome mobile and safari mobile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24617710/different-gyroscope-values-in-chrome-mobile-and-safari-mobile)

[Testing hardware support in Javascript for device orientation events of the iPhone 3GS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9077325/testing-hardware-support-in-javascript-for-device-orientation-events-of-the-ipho)